# Jquery Terminal In MVC Doesnt Work For Me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-terminal

Just implemented the http://terminal.jcubic.pl/#demo on my project in cloud9. It works like a charm and does everything its supposed to.

Project = https://ide.c9.io/wigge/andreas-cv

Website = andreas-cv-wigge.c9users.io/kol.html

Now to the problem.
I want it to work in my MVC project in visual studios and as of now, it doesnt.

MVC problem = http://gyazo.com/c24931d3479e6fe2df756e17af542f24 [image]

It doesnt seem like the terminal gets the script its supposed to or something, i can write in the terminal but not delete and click enter.

Here my code in MVC(i will give the js-code on files and link them in later) jsfiddle.net/19o39bx1/#&togetherjs=Ux8Mez1pOv

anyone got any idea what it can be?

or maybe someone got a better terminal for me to work with

Comment: Please do not link MWE, instead add it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error when I've included another jQuery after the code,

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.terminal-src.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').terminal(function(command, term) {
      term.echo(command);
    });
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Check if you didn't included another jQuery (maybe MVC added, check the source for the result page).

This is a bug in jQuery Terminal that can be fixed there.

Comment: Fixed in version 0.10.9.

Answer (score 1):

In `asp.ne MVC` project by default `jQuery` files are added to bundles ad included in default pages. I guess you have added your `jQuery` file referances also. And in [jcubic's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387194/jcubic) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384546/jquery-terminal-in-mvc-doesnt-work-for-me/37477305#37477305) was reproduced scenario when two jquery files were loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that JQuery terminal emulator scripts is launching before jQuery code is loaded , to prevent this try to implement Your scripts in this order:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>//download jquery
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.terminal/0.10.9/js/jquery.terminal.min.js"></script>//download jquery terminal
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.terminal/0.10.9/css/jquery.terminal.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>// jquery terminal styles
```

Comment: If terminal was included before JQuery the exception would be that jQuery is not defined.